# Twitter ping inside proxy failed but when open from browser it open

Tags: proxy, ping, tweetinvi

I have a problem: when I open twitter.com, it opens, but when use Tweetinvi it doesn’t work.

Therefore, I made this code:

```
var result = ping.Send("twitter.com");
if (result.Status != System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success)
{
    insertlogwithFilename("test ping  : 000X" );
}
```

I setup proxy configuration, but the ping does not work.

```
        TweetinviConfig.CurrentThreadSettings.HttpRequestTimeout = 5000000;
        TweetinviConfig.CurrentThreadSettings.UploadTimeout = 9000000;
        if (noproxy == "0")
        {
            TweetinviConfig.CurrentThreadSettings.ProxyURL = "http://" + proxyIP + ":" + proxyPort;

        }
        try
        {
            Auth.SetUserCredentials(cuskey, secret, accesstoken, useraccessse);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

            insertlogwithFilename("error in authentication :" + exp.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            var authenticatedUser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {

            insertlogwithFilename("error in user authentication :" + exp.Message);
        }
```

I test if connection to twitter is connected :

```
   public static void testconn()
    {

        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                using (var stream = client.OpenRead("https://www.twitter.com"))
                {
                    insertlogwithFilename("test stream  : 8666");
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            insertlogwithFilename("test stream  : 8766");
        }


    }
```

this block of code return true

```
    public static void testconnping()
    {
        var ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
        var result = ping.Send("twitter.com");
        if (result.Status != System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success)
        {
            insertlogwithFilename("test ping  : 8766" );
            //return false;
        }
        else
        {
            insertlogwithFilename("test ping  : 8666");
            //return true;
        }
    }
```

this block return false

Comment: There is actually no code whatsoever related with Tweetinvi in this sample.

Comment: I setup a configuration using 
                TweetinviConfig.CurrentThreadSettings.ProxyURL = "http://" + proxyIP + ":" + proxyPort;

Comment: but not work because when I ping on twitter.con no replay

Answer (score 0):

When you set up `TweetinviConfig.CurrentThreadSettings.ProxyURL` it does not mean that `ping.Send` will use this proxy. It means that Tweetinvi will use this proxy.

If you want to check if Tweetinvi is actually accessing the data, you will need to run the `GetAuthenticatedUser` method as explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Basics#lets-code-with-statics).

```
TweetinviConfig.CurrentThreadSettings.ProxyURL = "http://...";
ExceptionHandler.SwallowWebExceptions = false;
Auth.SetUserCredentials("CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", "ACCESS_TOKEN", "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");
var authenticatedUser = User.GetAuthenticatedUser();
```

Comment: I do this but the result is null

Comment: You have to stop with ping. Ping is NOT related with Tweetinvi. No matter what you change in Tweetinvi, you will not be able to ping. Are you saying that `authenticatedUser` is null? If so please change how the errors are handled by changing the `ExceptionHandler`. `ExceptionHandler.SwallowWebExceptions = false;`. .

Comment: More information there https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Exception-Handling

Comment: I solve it in another code . I build my own code to request REST json and use webrequest and webproxy. when I used tweetinvi the authorization is done but getteweets search not work . I think tweetinvi not used http protocol .